# NodeJS pull-stream setTimeout / setInterval / process.nextTick() all gets lost

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pull

I am using pull-stream for node: https://pull-stream.github.io

The problem is:

```
const x = () => {
   let y = () => {
     console.log('hello')
  }
  setInterval(() => y(), 2000)
}

x()

pull(infinite({x: 'hi'}), drain(event => console.log(event)))
```

what happens is that i constantly receive in console `"{x: 'hi'}"` but i never receive in console 'hello'

How is this possible?

Why does `setInterval` or either `setTimeout` but even `process.nextTick()` gets lost?

If i comment out the `pull()` part, i always and correctly see `"hello"` in console

How should i run `x()` and `pull()` on same file to work in parallel or anyway toghether  somehow?

Comment: You're not calling `x`

Comment: @robertklep corrected it

Comment: You're _calling_ `y` now, instead of passing it as reference :P

Comment: @robertklep and now? :D, my eyes can't keep this .... please HELP

Comment: You can just pass `y`: `setInterval(y, 2000)`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 how you mean please

Comment: just try it works  ```const x = () => {
   let y = () => {
     console.log('hello')
  }
  setInterval(() => y(), 2000)
}

x()```